# C# Timer not resetting after displaying a messagebox, just displaying a new messagebox every second

Tags: c#, timer, rss, intervals, podcast

Me and my friend are creating a podcastplayer. Every 30 minutes, 60 minutes or 2hrs the program should look through the rss feed and see if a new episode has been released. If so, the list of episodes in our program should be refreshed with the new episode added.

SO, now we're trying to use the System.Timers.Timer class to set an interval for executing our method to look for new episodes. To just test our method we just want to print out a messagebox every 10 seconds. But after 10 seconds the program just keeps instansiating new messageboxes. How do we make the timer reset and display just one new messagebox after 10 seconds? Is it because we're using a messagebox? Will the timer actually reset if we do something else besides displaying a messagebox? We tried printing out information into the console but the same problem occured.

Here's our code:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

public static class TimerInitializer
{
public static Timer timer; // From System.Timers
public static void Start()
{
    timer = new Timer(10000); // Set up the timer for 10 seconds
    //
    // Type "_timer.Elapsed += " and press tab twice.
    //
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerElapsed);
    timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it
}

public static void timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
}


}
```

Comment: Not really sure about your question, but I think you need to stop the timer and then start it again after displaying messagebox, something like `timer.Enabled = false; MessageBox.Show("Hello"); timer.Enabled = true;`

Answer (score 3):

You could disable the timer when the `Timer.Elapsed` event fires, display the message, then re-enable the timer when the user dismisses the `MessageBox`:

```
public static void timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();              // stop the timer
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    timer.Start();             // restart it; you'll get another msg in 10 seconds
}
```

Normally, using `MessageBox.Show` blocks the UI thread, and you'll notice that you can't click on the UI while a message is displayed.

The [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) operates on its own thread, apart from the UI thread. When the interval elapses, it runs its code (in this case, displays a message), and then just keeps chugging along until the next interval elapses again. What you get is a whole lot of message boxes, none of them blocking the UI or each other.

You can [read more here](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/03/all-about-net-timers-comparison.html). The article is a little old but the info regarding different Timers is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox is a static class. MessageBox.Show() gives you a new object every time. I think MessageBoxes are also Dialogs that prevent the code from continuing, this might mess with your timer. I would suggest switching to using something else for testing. The easiest thing to do to verify you have the behaviour that you want is to use Console.WriteLine() with a test statement and look at the Console/Output window in Visual Studio.

Alternatively instead of using a message box create an additional single form with class level scope and showing and hiding the page to indicate your timer has expired.

See : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Hiding_and_Showing_Forms_in_C_Sharp